# How to check if any string contains sql injection in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-injection

We have created API in express. Our API is receiving payload as userInput but sometimes any user can enter some sql injection as userInput like this

**userInput**

```js
    OR 1=1\n OR 1=0\n OR x=x\n OR x=y\n OR 1=1#\n OR 1=0#\n OR x=x#\n 
    OR x=y#\n OR 1=1-- \n OR 1=0-- \n OR x=x-- \n OR x=y-- \n OR 
    3409=3409 AND ('pytW' LIKE 'pytW\n OR 3409=3409 AND ('pytW' LIKE 
    'pytY\n HAVING 1=1\n HAVING 1=0\n HAVING 1=1#\n HAVING 1=0#\n 
    HAVING 1=1-- \n HAVING 1=0-- \n AND 1=1\n AND 1=0\n AND 1=1-- \n 
    AND 1=0-- \n AND 1=1#\n AND 1=0#\n AND 1=1 AND '%'='\n AND 1=0 
    AND '%'='\n AND 1083=1083 AND (1427=1427\n AND 7506=9091 AND 
    (5913=5913\n AND 1083=1083 AND ('1427=1427\n AND 7506=9091 AND 
    ('5913=5913\n AND 7300=7300 AND 'pKlZ'='pKlZ\n AND 7300=7300 AND 
    'pKlZ'='pKlY\n AND 7300=7300 AND ('pKlZ'='pKlZ\n AND 7300=7300 
    AND ('pKlZ'='pKlY\n AS INJECTX WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1\n AS INJECTX 
    WHERE 1=1 AND 1=0\n AS INJECTX WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1#\n AS INJECTX 
    WHERE 1=1 AND 1=0#\n AS INJECTX WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1--\n AS INJECTX 
    WHERE 1=1 AND 1=0--\n WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1\n WHERE 1=1 AND 1=0\n 
    WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1#\n WHERE 1=1 AND 1=0#\n WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1--\n 
    WHERE 1=1 AND 1=0--\n ORDER BY 1-- \n ORDER BY 2-- \n ORDER BY 3- 
    - \n ORDER BY 4-- \n ORDER BY 5-- \n ORDER BY 6-- \n ORDER BY 7-- 
    \n ORDER BY 8-- \n ORDER BY 9-- \n ORDER BY 10-- \n ORDER BY 11-- 
    \n ORDER BY 12-- \n ORDER BY 13-- \n ORDER BY 14-- \n ORDER BY 
    15-- \n ORDER BY 16-- \n ORDER BY 17-- \n ORDER BY 18-- \n ORDER 
    BY 19-- \n ORDER BY 20-- \n ORDER BY 21-- \n ORDER BY 22-- \n 
    ORDER BY 23-- \n ORDER BY 24-- \n ORDER BY 25-- \n ORDER BY 26-- 
    \n ORDER BY 27-- \n ORDER BY 28-- \n ORDER BY 29-- \n ORDER BY 
    30-- \n ORDER BY 31337-- \n ORDER BY 1# \n ORDER BY 2# \n ORDER 
    BY 3# \n ORDER BY 4# \n ORDER BY 5# \n ORDER BY 6# \n ORDER BY 7# 
    \n ORDER BY 8# \n ORDER BY 9# \n ORDER BY 10# \n ORDER BY 11# \n 
    ORDER BY 12# \n ORDER BY 13# \n ORDER BY 14# \n ORDER BY 15# \n 
    ORDER BY 16# \n ORDER BY 17# \n ORDER BY 18# \n ORDER BY 19# \n 
    ORDER BY 20# \n ORDER BY 21# \n ORDER BY 22# \n ORDER BY 23# \n 
    ORDER BY 24# \n ORDER BY 25# \n ORDER BY 26# \n ORDER BY 27# \n 
    ORDER BY 28# \n ORDER BY 29# \n ORDER BY 30#\n ORDER BY 31337#\n 
    ORDER BY 1 \n ORDER BY 2 \n ORDER BY 3 \n ORDER BY 4 \n ORDER BY 
    5 \n ORDER BY 6 \n ORDER BY 7 \n ORDER BY 8 \n ORDER BY 9 \n 
    ORDER BY 10 \n ORDER BY 11 \n ORDER BY 12 \n ORDER BY 13 \n ORDER 
    BY 14 \n ORDER BY 15 \n ORDER BY 16 \n ORDER BY 17 \n ORDER BY 18 
    \n ORDER BY 19 \n ORDER BY 20 \n ORDER BY 21 \n ORDER BY 22 \n 
    ORDER BY 23 \n ORDER BY 24 \n ORDER BY 25 \n ORDER BY 26 \n ORDER 
    BY 27 \n ORDER BY 28 \n ORDER BY 29 \n ORDER BY 30 \n ORDER BY 
    31337 \n RLIKE (SELECT (CASE WHEN (4346=4346) THEN 0x61646d696e 
    ELSE 0x28 END)) AND 'Txws'='\n RLIKE (SELECT (CASE WHEN 
    (4346=4347) THEN 0x61646d696e ELSE 0x28 END)) AND 
    'Txws'='\nIF(7423=7424) SELECT 7423 ELSE DROP FUNCTION xcjl-- 
    \nIF(7423=7423) SELECT 7423 ELSE DROP FUNCTION xcjl--\n%' AND 
    8310=8310 AND '%'='\n%' AND 8310=8311 AND '%'='\n and (select 
    substring(@@version,1,1))='X'\n and (select 
    substring(@@version,1,1))='M'\n and (select 
    substring(@@version,2,1))='i'\n and (select 
    substring(@@version,2,1))='y'\n and (select 
    substring(@@version,3,1))='c'\n and (select 
    substring(@@version,3,1))='S'\n and (select 
    substring(@@version,3,1))='X'
```

I want to check if the userInput is sql injection like above then I want to stop such requests and doesn't want to process further. How can I check if user has entered sql injection as userInput in our API

Answer (score 3):

**This is generally a very, very bad idea** as you're never going to be able to fully block out all permutations of SQL injections.

What you're better off doing is using [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

That will achieve your overall goal of blocking injection.